# Web Scraping no table HTML content element into Pandas Table

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, web-scraping

I need to scrape a website which has a 'table' like paragraph and I want to put it into a pandas table on python.
This is the website link: '[Website Link](https://www.civivi.com/collections/all-products/products/civivi-rustic-gent-lockback-knife-c914-g10-d2%22)

I need to get the Name, Price and the description of the page and put it all in a DataFrame format. The problem is that I can scrape all of it individually, but I can't get them to a proper DataFrame.

Here is what I have done so far:

```
I get the product links first because I need to scrape multiple pages:
baseURL = 'https://www.civivi.com'
product_links = []
for x in range (1,3):
    HTML = requests.get(f'https://www.civivi.com/collections/all-products/price-range_-70?page={x}',HEADER)
    #HTML.status_code
    Booti= soup(HTML.content, "lxml")
    knife_items = Booti.find_all('div',class_= "product-list product-list--collection product-list--with-sidebar")
    
    for items in knife_items:
        for links in items.findAll('a', attrs = {'class' : 'product-item__image-wrapper product-item__image-wrapper--with-secondary'}, href = True):
            product_links.append(baseURL + links['href'])
```

And then I scrape the individual web pages here:

```
Name = []
Price = []
Specific = []
for links in product_links:
#testlinks = "https://www.civivi.com/collections/all-products/products/civivi-rustic-gent-lockback-knife-c914-g10-d2"
    HTML2 = requests.get(links, HEADER)
    Booti2 = soup(HTML2.content,"html.parser") 
    try:
        for N in Booti2.findAll('h1',{'class': "product-meta__title heading h1" }):
            Name.append(N.text.replace('\n', '').strip())
        for P in Booti2.findAll('span',{'class': "price" }):
            Price.append(P.text.replace('\n', '').strip())
        Contents = Booti2.find('div',class_= "rte text--pull")
        for S in Contents.find_all('span'):
            Specific.append(S.text)

    except:
        continue
```

So I need to get all the information in this format:

```
         Name.     | | Price          || Model Number  Model Name. Overall Length
|------------------| |----------------||-------------| ---------||----------------|
| Product Name 1   | |  $$            ||  XXXX       |  ABC.    ||   XX"/XXcm.    |  
| Product Name 2   | |  $$            ||  XXXX       |  ABC.    ||   XX"/XXcm.    |
| Product Name 3   | |  $$            ||  XXXX       |  ABC.    ||   XX"/XXcm.    | 
| Product Name 4   | |  $$            ||  XXXX       |  ABC.    ||   XX"/XXcm.    |
```

...and so on with rest of the columns from the web pages.
Any help would be appreciated!!
Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use the `find('p')` in the class `rte text--pull"` and use then `get_text` with a separator as argument (`\n`). Then, use the following regular expressions (or split the `text` variable, find the keyword and remove from the string) to get only the desired information. With the list `rows` in place, you can create the dataframe with `pd.DataFrame(rows)`.

```py
import re # import regex to get knife model and length
rows = [] # create list to hold dataframe rows

for links in product_links:
    HTML2 = requests.get(links)
    Booti2 = soup(HTML2.content,"html.parser")
    try:
        name = Booti2.find('h1',{'class': "product-meta__title heading h1" }).get_text()
        price =  Booti2.find('span',{'class': "price" }).get_text()
        Contents = Booti2.find('div',class_= "rte text--pull")
        text = Contents.find('p').get_text(separator='\n')
        model_num = re.search('Model Number: (.+?)\n', text).group(1)
        model_name = re.search('Model Name: (.+?)\n', text).group(1)
        overall_len = re.search('Overall Length: (.+?)\n', text).group(1)
        rows.append([name, price, model_num, model_name, overall_len])
    except:
        continue
```

In case you haven't done already, `import pandas as pd`.

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=['name', 'price', 'model_num', 'model_name', 'overall_len'])
print(df)
```

```py
                            name    price    model_num              model_name      overall_len
0   CIVIVI Altus Button Lock a...      $85     C20076-1                   Altus  7.12" / 180.8mm
1   CIVIVI Altus Button Lock a...      $90     C20076-3                   Altus  7.12" / 180.8mm
2   CIVIVI Altus Button Lock a...     $107   C20076-DS1                   Altus  7.12" / 180.8mm
3   CIVIVI Teton Tickler Fixed...  $258.50     C20072-1           Teton Tickler   10.16" / 258mm
4   CIVIVI Nox Flipper Knife G...   $76.50       C2110C                     NOx  6.80" / 172.7mm
...
...
40  CIVIVI Ortis Flipper Knife...     $105    C2013DS-1                   Ortis    7.48" / 190mm
41  CIVIVI Dogma Flipper Knife...   $79.50       C2014A                   Dogma   7.7" / 195.7mm
42  CIVIVI Dogma Flipper Knife...   $79.50       C2014B                   Dogma   7.7" / 195.7mm
43  CIVIVI Appalachian Drifter...      $98       C2015A     Appalachian Drifter   6.8" / 172.7mm
```